# Getting error while running node-mysql tutorial

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am running the code in the tutorial part of node-mysql and its giving me error

**Code**

```
var MySQLPool = require("mysql-pool").MySQLPool;
var pool = new MySQLPool({
  poolSize: 4,
  user:     'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test'
});

pool.query("SELECT 'Hello, World!' AS hello", function(err, rows, fields) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(rows[0].hello);
});

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  pool.query("SELECT SLEEP(2), ? AS i", [i], function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Slept: " + rows[0].i);
  });
}
```

**ERROR:**

> /home/comapq/Works/Nodejs/Codes/node_modules/mysql-pool/lib/mysql-pool/pool.js:158
>         for(var key in Client.prototype) {
>                              ^
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>           at MySQLPool._populate (/home/comapq/Works/Nodejs/Codes/node_modules/mysql-pool/lib/mysql-pool/pool.js:158:23)
>           at new MySQLPool (/home/comapq/Works/Nodejs/Codes/node_modules/mysql-pool/lib/mysql-pool/pool.js:44:7)
>           at Object. (/home/comapq/Works/Nodejs/Codes/test-mysql-3.js:2:12)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>           at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
>           at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of research I found the problem. You probably installed mysql like this:

```
npm install mysql
```

This grabs the latest mysql package that is 2.0.0-alpha5(development phase, mostly untested). You need to install the latest stable version of mysql:

```
npm install mysql@0.9.6
```